# Play! Framework JPA and GroupBy

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, group-by, ebean

Play! Framework does not have group by function. This lack of functionality really starts to irritate me. How do I workaround that? I want `byRouteId` to group by trip_headsign. Simple raw query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM trips
WHERE route_id = 1070
GROUP BY trip_headsign
```

This is my Trip.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="trips")
public class Trip extends Model {

    @Constraints.Required
    public String route_id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String service_id;
    @Id
    public String trip_id;
    public String trip_headsign;
    public String direction_id;
    public String block_id;
    public String shape_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="route_id")
    public TRoute troute;

    public static List<Trip> byRouteId(String route_id) {
        List<Trip> trips = 
            Trip.find
            .fetch("troute") // fetch TRoute properties.
            .where().like("route_id", route_id)
            .findList();
        return trips;
    }

    public static Finder<String, Trip> find = new Finder(
            String.class, Trip.class
    );

}
```

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ebean/30NW-wmP5k0/Yk3UOk8YKIgJ) might help you. Can you test if one of the methods work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a raw SQL query instead by using the createNativeQuery function from the EntityManager class from javax.persistence.

```
EntityManager em = play.db.jpa.JPA.em();
List<Trip> tripList = em.createNativeQuery("insert raw sql query here").getResultList();
```

Comment: [RuntimeException: No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]]